# Zend framework - how to pass variable to the template?

Tags: php, zend-framework

in ZF2, how can i pass a variable to the following template.phtml?

for example i am loading my template.phtml as following in the home page:

```
<?=$this->render("layout/forms/template");?>
```

where `template.phtml` has following code, but i need to print something inside that template here: `<?=$this->????????;?>` by passing value from: `<?=$this->render("layout/forms/template");?>`

```
<h1 class="free-trial-title">More Information: <?=$this->????????;?></h1>
<section class="free-trial-form">
  <input type="text" name="txtName" id="txtName"  placeholder="Full Name"/><em>*</em><br/>

  <a class="read-more" id="btnContactMoreInfo" nohref>SUBMIT</a>  

</section>
```

How can i pass the value from home page to that template.phtml please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you render the additional view as a partial, you should have no problems.

```
<?php echo $this->partial('partial.phtml', array(
    'from' => 'Team Framework',
    'subject' => 'view partials')); ?>
```

Source: 
http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.partial.html